# C++: references and smart pointers - is there such a thing as a smart reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

Initially references have been introduced to C++ to hide the ugly pointer syntax much like many modern program languages do.

Now, with smart pointers it looks to me like we have to (again) explicitly use `ptr->element` or `*ptr.element` instead of just `reference.element`.

Is this the price we have to pay for having explicit control over ownership, i.e. being able to either keep it or move it on?

Or do I miss something...?

Comment: Reference is not a holder of something by idea I think.

Comment: References are not objects (as defined by the Standard) they are just a name alias.  So there is no storage associated with them; therefore they can not be made smart.

Comment: C++ terminology may not be semantically identical to the terminology used in other modern programming languages.  For example, a C++ reference is not the same as a Java reference.

Comment: Sure: a "smart reference" is the same as a "reference". References don't need to be "smart".

Comment: @RichardCritten however, since we live in a real world and standard needs to be implemented, references *do* occupy space unless ompimised away, which doesn't always happen.

Comment: @Fureeish not always.  References can just be an alias for some variable in local scope eg `int & ra17 = a[17];`  The compiler can just substitute `a[17]` when we use  `ra17`.

Comment: @RichardCritten the key word is *can*. It is absolutely not obligated to.

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointer are one of the few cases where it makes sense that there is something like `->`, because there are two different member that you can access with it. Look at this example:

```
shared_pointer<string> a(new string);
cout << a->size() << a.use_count << endl;
```

There are member functions of a shared_pointer, which is useful for managing it and you can access the members of the managed object. It would be a mess if it would use the same syntax and it could create name clashes.